# Is there a way in Photoshop to apply a mask to a single Smart Filter?

Tags: software, post-processing, photoshop

I like using Smart Filters because they let me adjust things later, and because I get a mask to control where the filters are applied.

The problem is that this mask applies to all the smart filters present on a given object.

Suppose I've got a photo and I want to apply the Lens Correction filter to the whole photo. On the same photo, I want to apply the Smart Sharpen filter. But I want to apply a mask to this filter. Can I do that?

Right now I've been duplicating the smart object and applying the filter I want to mask individually on to the top copy, and then masking the top copy. But this is a pain, and it takes incredible amounts of memory and disk space.

**Is there a good way to apply a mask to a single smart filter?**

Comment: This question falls into a gray area on the site. Generally, "how do I get a specific post-processing effect using software" questions have been considered on topic, while "how do I use a feature of a certain software package" questions not, even when that feature can be used in photo processing. I'm not complaining, just noting. (That lack of a focus on software operation is why there aren't existing tags to match your question.)

Comment: @mattdm: You FAQs state that questions on "photographic processing or retouching" are on-topic. They also say that questions about "Image Manipulation (outside of the Photography context)" are off-topic. Mine falls into the first category and not the second (I want to use this in a photography context). If questions like mine are not allowed or not appreciated on the site, you should probably update your FAQs :P.

Comment: Like I said, gray area. There's plenty of room to disagree about what "In a photographic context" means. (Is just saying "I want to use this on a photo" enough? Maybe it is!)  This discussion probably should be continued on http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/ — as far as I am aware, the distinction has been fairly squishy over the past year.

Comment: While I think this **is on topic** for us since its being used in a photographic context - I do think you'd get better answers at graphics.stackexchange.com or maybe even super user.  We toss *many* of the photoshop questions that way because they're not in a strictly photographic sense.  If there isn't any reasonable answers in a day or so, we may want to flag it to migrate.

Comment: @rfusca That sounds quite reasonable. We'll see how it goes.

Comment: Meta: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/where-do-we-draw-the-line-on-photoshop-and-similar-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layer mask applies to all the filters for the smart object.  However there is a workaround I've seen in a video.  The below link, an article by Deke McClelland, seems to use the same trick (you create a smart object within the original smart object, so they are nested, and you then get additional layer masks). This doesn't use up a lot of additional memory or disk space

http://layersmagazine.com/nesting-smart-objects-for-multimask-effects-in-photoshop.html